# Angular2 unit test Http MockBackend issue - Cannot read property merge of undefined at mergeOptions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, http, jasmine

Angular2 unit test Http MockBackend issue - Cannot read property merge of undefined at mergeOptions.

I'm trying to do a basic unit test for my http get promise.

The typescript compiler works fine.
But when I run npm run test with karma runner I get the below error.

**This is the gitbash error I'm getting: Cannot read property 'merge' of      undefined at mergeOptions.**

**This is my code:**

```
 import {Injectable} from 'angular2/angular2';
 import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';

 @Injectable()

 export class FirebaseService{
   headers: Headers;

   constructor(public http?: Http) {   
     this.headers = new Headers();
     this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   }

   public getSpotifyTracks = ():Promise<Object> =>{ 
       return this.http
        .get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/0eGsygTp906u18L0Oimnem', {headers:this.headers})
        .map((response) => {
           return response.json()
        }).toPromise();  
   }
 }
```

**This is my test:**

```
 import {beforeEach, ddescribe, describe, expect, iit, inject, it, xit, injectAsync, beforeEachProviders, fakeAsync, tick} from 'angular2/testing';
 import {provide, Injector, bind} from 'angular2/angular2';
 import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions} from 'angular2/http';

 import {FirebaseService} from '../app/firebase-service';

 describe('Spotify Service Calls', () => {
     beforeEachProviders(() => [    
         MockBackend,
         BaseRequestOptions,
         provide(Http, {useFactory:
             function(backend, defaultOptions) {
                 return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
             },
             deps: [MockBackend]})
     ]);

     //This test doesnt work??????????????
     it('getting tracks', inject([Http], (http) => {
         var firebaseService = new FirebaseService(http);
         var response;

         firebaseService.getSpotifyTracks().then((res) => {
             response = res;
             expect(response).not.toBe(null);
         });
     }));    
 });
```

Comment: Anyone had this error before?

Comment: do you need to mock the response coming back from that HTTP call

Comment: I have no idea, the error doesn't make sense. I think the problem is that I'm injecting http into my constructor and the test doesn't like it?

Comment: yeah, I just updated Angular last night and my tests started failing...guess that's what you get with an alpha product...if I figure out my issues, I'll relay you the fixes so maybe they can help

Answer (score 0):

I had updated to alpha.46 and it broke a lot of stuff. One thing is that `http.get(...)` calls no longer return an Observable with a `.map` method on them.

See if replacing the `.map` with something like

```
return this.http
    .get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/0eGsygTp906u18L0Oimnem', {headers:this.headers})
    .subscribe((response) => {
       return response.json()
    }).toPromise();
```

That's what I did and it works, not sure how "right" this is though...

Comment: Thank you I will try that today and let you know

Comment: Hi gonzofish, I've tried changing the code to what you suggested and the typescript compiler still compiles fine with the change. Which is good, however, the unit test still fails.

I seems not to like the constructor section where the http is injected.

This line: constructor(public http?: Http) {   }

Comment: @AngularM have you fixed this issue ? I am having the same issue, my service constructor has a Http injector. Unit tests error says Cannot resolve all parameters for MockService,  Make sure they all have valid type or annotations. I have a MockService that extends from the Actual Service.